# Can I use this code in oracle pl/sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying this code in PL/SQL developer but it's not executing nothing. How can I use this code in order to find all tables which column values contains a specific value?

```
declare
    num_rows number;
    sql_text varchar2(250);
    sql_info varchar2(100);
begin
    dbms_output.enable(1000000);
    for x in (select table_name, column_name from all_tab_columns
               where data_type in ('VARCHAR','VARCHAR2','CHAR')
                 and owner='SYSTEM')
    loop
         sql_text:='select count(*) into :num_rows from SYSTEM.'||x.table_name||' where '||x.column_name||' like ''%10305698%''';
         -- dbms_output.put_line (sql_text);
         execute immediate sql_text into num_rows;
         if num_rows>0 
         then 
              sql_info:='Table: '||x.table_name||' contains the string';
              dbms_output.put_line (sql_info);
         end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Have you `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Does your user have permission to view SYSTEM tables?  Maybe the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS query is not returning anything for you.

Comment: By the way, `data_type in ('VARCHAR','VARCHAR2','CHAR')` can be simplified to `data_type like '%CHAR%'`.

Comment: Also, PL/SQL Developer is not an Oracle product.

Answer (score 1):

The below demonstration is to [**Search for a VALUE in all COLUMNS of all TABLES in an entire SCHEMA**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/):

- Search a **CHARACTER type**

Let's look for the value `KING` in `SCOTT` schema.

```
SQL> variable val varchar2(10)
SQL> exec :val := 'KING'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",
  2    SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
  3    SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"
  4  FROM cols,
  5    TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
  6    || column_name
  7    || ' from '
  8    || table_name
  9    || ' where upper('
 10    || column_name
 11    || ') like upper(''%'
 12    || :val
 13    || '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) t
 14  ORDER BY "Table"
 15  /

Searchword  Table          Column
----------- -------------- --------------
KING        EMP            ENAME

SQL>
```

- Search a **NUMERIC type**

Let's look for the value `20` in `SCOTT` schema.

```
SQL> variable val NUMBER
SQL> exec :val := 20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",
  2    SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
  3    SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"
  4  FROM cols,
  5    TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
  6    || column_name
  7    || ' from '
  8    || table_name
  9    || ' where upper('
 10    || column_name
 11    || ') like upper(''%'
 12    || :val
 13    || '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) t
 14  ORDER BY "Table"
 15  /

Searchword  Table          Column
----------- -------------- --------------
20          DEPT           DEPTNO
20          EMP            DEPTNO
20          EMP            HIREDATE
20          SALGRADE       HISAL
20          SALGRADE       LOSAL

SQL>
```

Comment: what is your compiler?

Comment: The demonstration I have shown on SQL*Plus, it will run on SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer as well.

Comment: @Jahon the PL/SQL compiler is in the database.

Comment: Your code is running is PL/SQL Developer but result not showing

Comment: Perhaps cols view returns nothing for you.